# Unable to set innerHTML of null error . Although, html ID is present

Tags: javascript, html

I'm getting a "cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null from getElementById, but my HTML element has the right ID, and so does my script.

I'm new to JavaScript so if I'm missing something obvious please tell me! Thanks!

Here's the full fiddle: 
FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/xPLD4/1/

This is the section that i'm having problems with.
Script:

```
function prices() {
   document.getElementById("regular").innerHTML = '$' + setPrices.regular + ' /gallon';
   document.getElementById("regPlus").innerHTML = '$' + setPrices.regularPlus + ' /gallon';
   document.getElementById("premium").innerHTML = '$' + setPrices.premium + ' /gallon';
   document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Status: No Automobile Present";
   var carPresent = false;
}

//generates prices on pump display
window.onload = prices;

var pumpDisplayOne = 1000;
document.getElementById("pumpDisplayOne").innerHTML = "Total gallons pumped on this pump: " + pumpDisplayOne;
```

HTML:

```
<h3>Pump 1</h3>
<h4 id="pumpDisplayOne">Gallons</h4>
<button type="button" class="paybutton" onclick="pay()">Pay!</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must Run Your javascript code after DOMReady, If your `script` tag is in `head`, move down before all `</body>`, or put all code in `onload` event.
Here is my [jsFiddle update](http://jsfiddle.net/xPLD4/4/), that works.

Comment: -1 a. the scripts CAN be in the `head` and b. your fiddle does NOT work - as it displays the correction before the user clicked on the button!

Comment: what exactly did you change?

Comment: alfasin, the pumpDisplayOne is a global variable that will be added to once the user pumps the gas with the amount they pump. example: user says they have 13 gallons in the car that holds 20 gallons. The total gallons pumped will update once the user has executed the pay() function with 1007 gallons. The default status of the counter is 1000

Comment: @alfasin, when script is in head tag, browser runs it before domready, in javascript the `document.getElementById("pumpDisplayOne").innerHTML` is in global scope, so browser set the innerHTML of pumpDisplayOne before it creates the element. Because of that I have changed the run priority, and told the reason why that statement doesn't work. So please be attentive before hit on "-" button ;)

Comment: Nothing) only the event, when to run script from onLoad to onDomready, at the left in jsFiddle.

Comment: If my answer works how You want, You can move down your <script> tag after the html, or put all javasctipt code in function (e.g. loaded), and add `onload="loaded()"` in your body tag

Comment: I already have prices() to load when the body element is loaded.

Comment: I'm not seeing any changes in the fiddle, so that's why i'm confused.

Comment: Is my variant that what You want ?

Comment: No it doesn't work! do you really want to display 1000 and all the buttons not to work ? and @VaheShadunts what you did is like offering a plaster to someone that fell from a 10 story building...

Comment: @alfasin, i disagree with nested functions too, but the problem which user2281178 provided, was in domready.